# SQL: breaking a tie

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have an SQL database structured like Major League Baseball. It has an American League and National League, which contain divisions, which contain teams, which have Win/Loss records and contain players.

My League table has: |league_name|league_id(primary key)|wild card|

Where wild card is a foreign key teamID that is the best team in a division who doesn't lead that division.

Here is my trigger to update wild card when I update my Z_TEAMS table (where the win/loss records are kept):

```
UPDATE Z_LEAGUES
SET `Z_LEAGUES`.`Wild Card` = (SELECT teamID
                           FROM Z_TEAMS
                           WHERE (teamWins/teamLoss) = 
                           (SELECT MAX(teamWins/teamLoss) FROM Z_TEAMS, 
                           Z_DIVISIONS WHERE Z_TEAMS.divID = 
                           Z_DIVISIONS.divID AND Z_DIVISIONS.leagueID = 
                           Z_LEAGUES.leagueID AND Z_TEAMS.teamID != Z_DIVISIONS.divLeader))
```

It usually works well and picks the correct team every time Z_TEAMS is updated. However, if I try to update Z_TEAMS so that 2 teams have the same record and both are candidates for wild card, the trigger returns more than one row and restricts the update.

My question is: How can I break this tie? I am open to displaying both teams in the wild card spot, or arbitrarily picking one, or picking by say, alphabetical order. I'm fairly new to SQL and can't figure this out.

Comment: This isn't so much a MySQL question as it is about what kind of algorithm you should develop. You can develop any tie breaker you or your users deem to be reasonable. You might look at the two tied teams and determine which one has the best record against each other. And if that results in a tie the team with the most runs for the season, and on and on this can go. Look at the U.S. Constitution and see how ties in the electoral college are handled. You need some kind of tie breaker algorithm and what that is is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Z_LEAGUES
SET `Z_LEAGUES`.`Wild Card` = 
(SELECT teamID
 FROM Z_TEAMS
 WHERE (teamWins/teamLoss) = 
    (SELECT MAX(teamWins/teamLoss) 
     FROM Z_TEAMS, Z_DIVISIONS 
     WHERE Z_TEAMS.divID = Z_DIVISIONS.divID 
       AND Z_DIVISIONS.leagueID = Z_LEAGUES.leagueID 
       AND Z_TEAMS.teamID != Z_DIVISIONS.divLeader)
 ORDER BY teamID
 Limit 1)
```

Added the last 2 lines to your base query.

Limit will limit the output rows, and order by will order them for precitability of which row will be selected.

You may use `order by teamID desc` to reverse sort.